# Change palette for Chord Diagram in Bokeh

Tags: python, graph, visualization, bokeh, chord-diagram

I am using the Bokeh library to generate a chord diagram. The diagram itself generates more-or-less just fine, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to change the palette. As far as I can gather, most charts in Bokeh can have an optional `palette` argument, but adding this doesn't change the palette. Am I missing something?

```
import bokeh
from bokeh.charts import Chord
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.palettes import inferno

chord_diagram = Chord(forchord, source='nameA', target='nameB', palette= inferno(256))
show(chord_diagram)
```

If some data would help:

```
nameA_lst = ['Creb5','Creb5','JDP2(var.2)','JDP2(var.2)',
             'Creb5','JDP2(var.2)','ATF7','ATF','ATF7','Creb5']
nameB_lst = ['STAT3','STAT1','STAT3','STAT1','Stat4',
             'Stat4','STAT3','STAT1','Stat4','Stat5a::Stat5b']
forchord = pd.DataFrame({'nameA': nameA_lst, 'nameB': nameB_lst})
forchord.head()
    nameA   nameB
0   Creb5   STAT3
1   Creb5   STAT1
2   JDP2(var.2) STAT3
3   JDP2(var.2) STAT1
4   Creb5   Stat4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chord doesn't use palette, it use color wheel like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is a bit outdated as `bokeh.charts` has been deprecated ([What to use instead of bokeh.charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170086/what-to-use-instead-of-bokeh-charts)), instead you can use Holoviews which use colormaps, as described here: http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Colormaps.html