# What to use instead of bokeh.charts

Tags: python, charts, bokeh

I am trying to run some code written by someone else, which contains the line

```
from bokeh.charts import Bar
```

When I run this in the Anaconda Prompt, I get the message "No module named 'bokeh.charts'".

I have installed bokeh 0.12.13, so the problem isn't that I haven't installed it. Indeed, other bokeh modules run fine.

I have noticed on the bokeh website that the 'charts' module says that it refers to a previous version (see https://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.12.4/docs/reference/charts.html).

Does the latest version not have bokeh.charts? If so, is there an alternative?

Comment: `bokeh.charts` has been moved to a separate project named `bkcharts`. You can try reading up on that one, or try the `bokeh.plotting` API.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`bokeh.charts` was deprecated quite a long time ago, and subsequently removed. The code still exists in the [`bokeh/bkcharts`](https://github.com/bokeh/bkcharts) repository on GitHub, however it is entirely unmaintained, and I would not recommend anyone to use it at this point.

Depending on what you want to do, stable and supported `bokeh.plotting` may be sufficient. There have been lots of improvements and many chart types that previously required `bokeh.charts` are now simple to make with `bokeh.plotting`. See the [Handling Categorical Data](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) section of the User's guide for example.

Otherwise, if you want a very high level API, built on top of Bokeh, that supports more advanced interactive statistical and GIS chart types, have a look at [Holoviews](http://holoviews.org/).

Comment: Thanks @bigreddot! But how can we build chord diagram from scratch? Do you have any tips or good resources?

Comment: Chord plots are now possible with Holoviews, which is built on top of Bokeh: http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/route_chord.html#bokeh-gallery-route-chord