# ImportError: cannot import name 'Bar'

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

Getting same error for below all three line, please help me to import Bar from bokeh library. I spent almost 3 hours but no solution.

```
-> from bokeh.plotting import Bar
-> from bokeh.io import Bar
-> from bokeh.charts import Bar

   ImportError: cannot import name 'Bar'
```

Comment: Maybe it can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170086/what-to-use-instead-of-bokeh-charts

Comment: the module `bokeh.charts` for long time has been removed and deprecated

Comment: change `from bokeh.plotting import Bar` to `from bokeh.plotting import figure, show`

Comment: Thanks, It helped @Joe

Comment: Thanks for the help. @MEdwin

Comment: Can you point to where you ran across this very old out of date usage? Perhaps we can delete or correct it, or message he author to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `bokeh.charts` for long time has been removed and deprecated. Use `bokeh.plotting`  instead. Try this. Let me know if it works.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

region = ["Global", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America"]
volume = [3010, 1642, 716, 844]

p = figure(x_range=region)
p.vbar(x=region, top=volume, width=0.9)

show(p)
```

Comment: and Marked as answered. @MEdwin